# Pass params to mapGetters in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, getter

Good day.

I use modules in my vue.js project. Now i need to get filtered data from getter, but don't undestand how provide params.

I want provide 'name' parameter to Getter. How i can do it in Component.vue ?

```js
/*State in vuex*/
state: {
   tempMessageValues: [
            { name: 'RU', status: 'none', selected: false },
            { name: 'BY', status: 'none', selected: false },
            { name: 'KG', status: 'none', selected: false }
        ]
}

/*Getters*/

import * as types from '../types';

export default {
    [types.GETTERS.TEMP_MESSAGE_VALUES]: state => {
        return state.tempMessageValues.find(country => country.name === name);
    }
};

/*Types*/

export const GETTERS = {
    TEMP_MESSAGE_VALUES: 'shared/TEMP_MESSAGE_VALUES'
};

/*Code in Component.vue*/

import * as types from "./store/types";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      getTempMessValues: types.GETTERS.TEMP_MESSAGE_VALUES
    })
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs suggest using currying to pass params to a getter;

```
export default {
  [types.GETTERS.TEMP_MESSAGE_VALUES]: state => name =>
    state.tempMessageValues.find(country => country.name === name)
};
```

See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access for their example. You're essentially making your getter return a function the first time it's called.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, thanks. 
It works,  i can receive value in HTML through 
{{ getTempMessValues(country) }}  or in computed: 
getVal() {
      return this.getTempMessValues(this.country);
    //this.country = "RU" or "BY" or "KZ"
},

Comment: Doesn't this make the getter non-reactive?

Answer (score 0):

A way would be to return a function from the getter, which you can then use to pass a parameter in

```
export default {
[types.GETTERS.TEMP_MESSAGE_VALUES]: state => {
    return (name) => state.tempMessageValues.find(country => country.name === name);
}
};
```

Now you can pass a parameter to your getter by calling your function:

```
this.getTempMessValues('YourValue')
```